# Mass Distribution of common household objects around their volume

Tags: geospatial

Where can I find a list of household objects, together with their typical shape, mass, and (if possible moment) of inertia about some axis - preferably in an [SDF](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model)-like format?

Examples:

- furniture: table, chair, sofa, bookshelf, bed-frame
- appliances: microwave (standalone), fridge, fan, washing and drying machine
- furnishings: mattress, curtain, blind

It may be possible to get info on these from separate manufacturers. I'm looking for a central source where someone has already collected this information. I'm also not particular about the exact type of objects (say queen bed, and not king bed). All that matters is correctness of the information.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't even answer the "mass" part of your question, but may be of some help.

My first thought was to use wikidata, and this query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?weight WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P2067 ?weight .
}
```

gives you the weight of 252,132 items with some caveats:

- This gives you raw item numbers like "Q926610", not names or labels. The query times out if you try to add names, even if it's something as simple as the `rdfs:label` property. You can, of course, further manipulate this data further on your local machine (using a lookup table and the Unix "join" command, for example).
- Wikipedia (and thus Wikidata) isn't always accurate.
- I only looked at some of the data, but some of these are weights for people, not items. A more sophisticated query might be able to find just item weights.

Smaller but possibly more accurate sources that would require "scraping" or editing to put in a more machine-usable form:

- Professional movers have a vested interest in how much furniture weighs: http://www.ewtaz.com/images/uploads/average-weight-furniture-2.pdf
- Professional shippers are interested in the weight of shippable household items: https://www.parcl.com/education/customers/shipping_weight
- Physics engine and game developers are interested in simulating realistic weights. I couldn't find a great reference here, but https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/85821/? is an attempt to do this for SkyRim.
- This [UPC database](https://www.upcdatabase.com/) lists weights for some items, such as [this item](https://www.upcdatabase.com/item/018200001697). However, I'm not sure how useful that is, since I'm guessing it's mostly for items in fixed-size cans and bottles.

If anyone (OP or otherwise) is interested in helping me improve this answer, please contact me (contact info in profile)

Note for pedantic physicists: I realize weight and mass aren't the same thing, but, for Terran-bound beings, there is a simple conversion.